# golang diff type of functions provide "unresolved type”

Tags: go

Im using function like following which works

```
import (
   "m5/cmd/models"
)

func  TypeCommand(m Modules) string {

…

}
```

Now I want to change

```
func (m models.Modules) TypeCommand() string {

}
```

And now Im getting error “unresolved type modules” , why ? the first function is compiled ...

Comment: Can you provide the context of that function? More specifics the "package" and the "imports" from the top of that function file.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - done please check

Comment: If modules is defined in current package and it is not defined inside models. you cannot access it that's why the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add methods to types from outside the package in which they are defined. If you really feel it is necessary then the workaround is to define a new type which embeds the imported type and extend that. You will then have a type which includes all of the original methods as well as the new method:

```
import (
   "m5/cmd/models"
)

type myModule struct {
    models.Modules
}

func (m myModule) TypeCommand() string {
  // method code here
}
```

With this example `myModule` will have all of the exported fields and methods of `model.Modules` plus the `TypeCommand()` method.

Comment: It is important to mention that the `TypeCommand` method will have access only to **exported** fields and methods of type `models.Modules`.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur - yes - I should have been clearer. I will edit the answer to reflect this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only define method on a type within the same package. You cannot define method on type `Modules` outside package `models`.

From [Go specification on Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic parameter, the receiver. Its type must be of the form T or *T (possibly using parentheses) where T is a type name. The type denoted by T is called the receiver base type; **it must not be a pointer or interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the method**. The method is said to be bound to the base type and the method name is visible only within selectors for type T or *T.

Comment: but I cannot add the type from this package, is there some workaround?

Comment: @Jonneywolf None I know of.